# How can I change the color of First and Third Saturday of month in fullCalendar js?

Tags: php, jquery, fullcalendar

How can I change the color of **First** and **Third** Saturday of month in **fullCalendar** **js**?

Comment: Welcome! Stack Overflow is *not* a code writing service. 
We are always glad to help and support new coders but you need to help yourself first. 
You are expected to try to write the code yourself.
Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: also define what you want to color.. the header? the full column?

Comment: I assume you mean first and third saturday of each _month_? Not year? Or quarter? Unlikely I know, but it's always best to be 100% clear. Anyway, what have you done so far to try and solve your problem? We're here to help you with your attempt, not simply do your research and coding for you completely.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I wanted to add color for the first and third Saturday of every month. Finally, I came up with an answer.

Answer (score 0):

**1) Just add this to the js file**

```
viewRender: function(view) {
                    if(view.title){
                       var a= 1;
                          $('.fc-day.fc-sat').each(function() {                        
                                  $($(this)).addClass("sat"+a);                                   
                                 a++;
                               });                    
                       }
                    }
```

2) the add CSS to file

```
.sat1,.sat3{
    background-color: #FF1919 !important;
}
```